# Что выполняет этот обработчик?

Tags: javascript, события

Привет, нашел на просторах интернета такой код, и не могу его понять, что выполняет " event.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(customEvent)"?

```js
var li = document.querySelector('li');

li.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  debugger;
}, true);

li.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var customEvent = new CustomEvent('mySpecialEvent', {
    bubbles: true,
    detail: {
      data: 'foo'
    }
  });

  event.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
});


document.addEventListener('mySpecialEvent', function(event) {
  alert(event.detail.data);
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ну что разобрались?

Comment: Да, более-менее.

Comment: тогда закройте вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы инициировать событие `mySpecialEvent` используется метод `dispatchEvent`.В данном случае для объекта `event.currentTarget` (li) на котором поймали клик.Подробнее [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/dispatch-events#%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-dispatchevent)

```js
var li = document.querySelector('li');

li.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  debugger;
}, true);

li.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var customEvent = new CustomEvent('mySpecialEvent', {
    bubbles: true,
    detail: { data: 'foo' }
  });

  event.currentTarget.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
});


li.addEventListener('mySpecialEvent', function(event) {
  alert(event.detail.data);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>Item</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```